# Django/Apache old content after restart

Tags: python, django, apache, django-models, django-migrations

I have a strange problem with a website running on Django 1.8 and Apache.

I am trying to display a list of next week's upcoming events. After making modifications to the model, making and applying my migrations on the website, and restarting Apache, everything shows up fine. I have a python script queries and displays next week's days worth of events on the website. This week-to-week rollover of events is scheduled to happen shortly after midnight on the Saturday before the events take place.

Unfortunately, the events are not showing up on Saturday until I manually reload the Apache service. Also, by the time Monday rolls around, the site is again displaying old information until I *again* reload the Apache service. After the Monday reload, everything works as it should until the next Saturday.

I've checked all the crons, and there's nothing running that should make the site behave this way. I've also checked the ctime and mtime on all of the files and it does not appear that they've been changed or modified. I've also checked through the script and can find nothing that would be causing this behaviour.

Does anyone know what might be causing this or have another approach to solving this problem?

Thank you.

Here's the relevant code...

```
views.py

def index(request, starttime = datetime.now(), version = False):
# starttime: Datetime object for when to begin looking for events. Index pages are always a week.
starttime = datetime.now()
endtime = starttime + timedelta(7)
event_list = getEventsDB(EventList(), start = starttime, end = endtime)

event_calendar = getEventsDB(
    EventSeries.objects.get(event_slug = 'competition'),
    start = starttime, end = starttime + timedelta(7))
highlight_title = 'Competitions'

t = loader.get_template('event/index.html')

c = RequestContext(request, {
    'page_title': 'Events',
    'highlight_title': highlight_title,
    'event_list': event_list,
    'highlight': event_calendar,
    'event_series_list': EventSeries.objects.filter(active=True),
})

return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Comment: Please [show some code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - it will likely make it much easier to diagnose your issue!

Comment: Maybe apache is using some cache to return the response?

Comment: Don't forget execute `service apache reload` after changing your django's code.

Comment: Yep. I've used service apache reload each time. I used the wrong term in my original post. I should have said I reloaded apache rather than restarted the server.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here:

```
def index(request, starttime = datetime.now(), version = False):
```

There starttime is evaluated when the method is *defined*, which happens when the module is first imported - in other words, when the server is restarted. Don't put values there; instead, leave the default as None and check in the function itself:

```
def index(request, starttime=None, version = False):
    if starttime is None:
        starttime = datetime.now()
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a shot. I'm new to Django and Python and this is an inherited project. I wasn't sure why starttime was being given values twice, but I didn't think it would hurt anything apart from being redundant and a bit messy. Now I know better!